# For loop to initialise new instances in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to initiate new instances in a for loop? I currently am initialising 20 instances, but i would like to make it so that based on a number, it initialises the same amount instead of manually coding 20 different instances.

Currently i initilise a red particle like this within the main class:

```
    this.redParticle0 = new redParticle(
      this.stageWidth,
      this.stageHeight,
      10,
      7,
      'red',
      10,
      10
    );
```

Within the animate() function, i draw it to the canvas as follows:

```
    this.redParticle0.draw(
      this.ctx,
      this.stageWidth,
      this.stageHeight,
      this.partition
    );
```

I just want to know if there is a way within the main class to use a for loop to initialise lets say 20 automatically instead of manually coding 20 times.

Sorry for the nooby question, new to javascript and trying to learn.

Comment: You can, if you use the square brackets notation; you can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/n0sd4oh9/

Comment: @secan is there a reason this is preferred?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, the reason is that square brackets notation allows you to use variables and the result of expressions as key. You cannot do something like ```this[`redParticle${i}`] = new Whatever()``` using the dot notation.

Comment: @aabb1998, this snippet should be more relevant to your code: https://jsfiddle.net/qkw239vs/. It is the same concept as the previous one but with a level of complexity closer to what you might actually have.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, just to avoid any misunderstanding: the square bracket notation is not *always* preferable to the dot notation (in fact, I almost always use the dot notation) but it is the only way to handle variables used as object keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use a for loop to initialise multiple instances of a class. You would normally then store these in an array:

```js
class redParticle {
    constructor() {
       this.type = "red particle";
       this.color = "red";
    }
}

const particleCount = 20;

this.redParticles = [];

// Create our particles here in the for.. loop.
for(let i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) { 
    this.redParticles.push(new redParticle(
       this.stageWidth,
       this.stageHeight,
       10,
       7,
       'red',
       10,
       10
    ))
}

console.log("Particle count:", this.redParticles.length)
```

You could then draw like so:

```
this.redParticles.forEach(particle => particle.draw(
      this.ctx,
      this.stageWidth,
      this.stageHeight,
      this.partition
    )
)
```

or perhaps

```
function animate() {
   for(let particle of this.redParticles) {
       particle.draw(
           this.ctx,
           this.stageWidth,
           this.stageHeight,
           this.partition
       );
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to call the `draw` function in a loop. So you could add a loop that goes through the `redParticles` array and calls `draw` on each particle.

Comment: Thank you so much. Managed to get it to work. Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, very glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use a loop in your constructor (or wherever). I think maybe the bit you're missing is that you'd use the bracket syntax instead of the dot syntax to refer to a property via an expression instead of by its literal name.

See this example:

```js
const particleSpace = new ParticleSpace();
particleSpace.makeParticles();
console.log(Object.keys(particleSpace));

function ParticleSpace(){
  this.makeParticles = function(){
    let i = -1;
    while(i++ < 20){
      // Use bracket syntax to build a property name
      this["redParticle" + i] = new RedParticle();
    }
  }
};

function RedParticle(){
  this.message = "I am red";
}
```